# Laravel project is only updated on development server

Tags: php, laravel, npm

I'm attempting to deploy a Laravel project I've been working on, using the Vuexy Admin Dashboard Template. When I start a development server, and proxy to its port, the content within the site is the most up-to-date version, but when I don't proxy it, and send it to the `public` directory, it's the original content that comes with the default panel. I have used `npm run production` to build the production version of the dashboard that I made my changes to, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you using CDN on live server?

Comment: No, all of the images and content and such are in folders in the same root directory.